# Would temporal difference learning be unbiased if the value function was initialized to zero?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference

I was reading this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/455000/398148) to a question that asked why TD learning was biased.
The answer showed that TD learning was biased due to the starting value of the value function:

\begin{align}
V_{n+1}(s) &= V_n(s) + \alpha[R + V(s') - V_n(s)] \\
&= (1-\alpha)V_n(s) + \alpha(R + V(s'))\\
&=(1 - \alpha)[V_{n-1}(s) + \alpha[R + V(s') - V_{n-1}(s)]] + \alpha(R + V(s'))\\
&= \ldots \\
&= (1-\alpha)^n V_1(s) + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha(1 - \alpha)^{i-1} (R + V(s'))
\end{align}

So, is TD learning unbiased with the value function initialized to zero since the bias term is dependent on the starting value of the value function?

Furthermore, if TD learning is unbiased in this case, are there disadvantages to initializing the value function to zero rather than a randomized initialization?

Comment: Can you please explain (as an edit to the post, not only a comment) what is  TD learning?